# Disable default InfoWindow

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Is there way to disable default InfoWindow per marker?

```
mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(marker -> {
    if(someCondition){
        return new CustomInfoWindow();
    } else {
        //no window
        return null;
    }
});
```

Returning null shows default white and empty InfoWindow. Is there way to hide it? Or even better ignore clicks on some markers?